# RSocket-CLI: Unresolved reference: clientTransport

Tags: java, kotlin, rsocket, rsocket-java

I ran into the error while starting the [rsocket-cli](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-cli):

[image]

The full log is [here](https://gist.github.com/akulik512/0ebc9ae5812553616eb9f0a583308ae5).

I did everything according to the [README.md](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-cli/blob/master/README.md), but I got this error at the first step. It's the `./gradlew --console plain installDist`.

What's the most interesting in the code this error looks like this:
[image]

[image]

I'm not sure but probably it can be important. I'm using the `Shell: zsh 5.8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsocket-kotlin has a snapshot build, and due a 0.13.0 build sometime soon.  It seems like the current TCP refactor relies on internal API.

I've raised https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-kotlin/issues/163

In the meantime if you want websocket support I'd comment that out.

Also there is a rsocket-java CLI you can use if this is still blocking you https://github.com/making/rsc

Apologies and thanks for flagging.

Comment: Hello Yuri! 
Thanks for your answer!
Unfortunately, I've seen your comment too late and raised this issue https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-cli/issues/122
Should I close it?